# Adding event to Google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been looking for a way to do this, but I haven't found it anywhere: how could I add an onClick event to a (multiple eventually) marker on a Google map?

I want to place a map on my website, a script that gets triggered (outside the map) when the user clicks a location on the map.

Comment: Where did you search? Ebay, amazon, facebook? On the right side under "Related"  you'll see a lot of results, and the related page for "Events" isn't hard to find in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents

Comment: I searched google, and found nothing at all. The closest I got was a question from 2009 about how to change the marker image. I also searched here on SO, and nothing showed up. It only showed up in the related questions after I posted this...

Comment: When you search for information related to an API you first should take a look at  the API-documentation(when available), that's what a documentation is meant for. Usually the documentations will be linked at the wiki-pages for a tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps/info

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   alert('i m clicked');
});
```